# Not all code executes, but program exits properly

Tags: c++, std

This is a program which is supposed to find circular primes below  certain `max` value. It works for `max<=1000`, but if `max=10000` , the program ends without errors, but does not print the last two lines to console, even though it always should. It also doesn't print any more circular primes out, but that might be my algorithm problem, and I will worry about it later.

Note: I'm using MVS 2010, and there are unnecessary `std::` before `cout`, because it sometimes says that cout is ambigous.

```
using namespace std;

int main(){

    const int max = 10000;
    int nrOfPrimes = 0;
    int* primes = findIfPrimes(max);
    for(int i = 2; i < max; i++){
        //check if number is prime
        if(primes[i] == 0){
            nrOfPrimes++;
            int l = 0;
            int* permutations = findPermutations(i, l);
            //variable saying lf all permutations are prime
            bool allPrime = true;
            //check all permutations, if they are not prime change allPrime
            for(int j = 0; j < l; j++){
                if(primes[permutations[j]] != 0){
                    allPrime = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            //if it wasnt circular prime- continue
            if(allPrime == false)
                continue;
            //if it was circular prime, change all permutations to "circular prime"
            std::cout << "Circular primes: ";
            for(int j = 0; j < l; j++){
                primes[permutations[j]] = 2;
                std::cout << permutations[j] << " " << endl;
            }
            std::cout << endl;
        }
    }

    //find total count
    int result = 0;
    for(int i = 2; i < max; i++)
    if(primes[i] == 2)
        result++;
    std::cout << "total number of primes " << nrOfPrimes << endl;
    std::cout << "total number of circular primes " << result << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Flush your output buffer.

Comment: @HotLicks It worked, but wasn't std::endl supposed to flush cout as well?

Comment: It's been a dozen years since I mucked with the cout stuff, but IIRC you get autoflush of the cout buffer only when you do a cin.

Answer (score 1):

Put just before `return 0` in `main()`:

```
bool fail = cout.fail();
cout.clear();
cout << fail << endl;
cin.ignore(cin.rdbuf()->in_avail()); // clears all remaining input
cin.get(); // waits for ENTER
```

What tells it for `fail`?

Do the same with `fail = cout.good();`. What tells it then?

Comment: 0 for both, code without and with "cout.flush()" after each circular primes.

Comment: @Xyzk: even when max <= 1000 and all works fine? 0 for cout.good() is strange, it should be 1. Thats why it doesn't output.

Comment: Then I have no idea. Maybe there is a problem with this ambiguities of cout. I work with VC2010 and never have problem with this. And yes, endl should flush - try `std::cout << std::endl;` without any manual flush.